# Routing internet on NAT server thru Squid proxy

Tags: squid, nat

I've configured a Squid proxy and a NAT instance and both are functioning fine.

Now I want to configure a proxy server on the NAT instance so that the internet on NAT is routed through the Squid proxy server.

This set up is configured on CentOS 6.3.

Comment: I believe a picture of your network setup might help a lot to determine how to best answer your question. Providing some additional information on how your devices are connected logically together seems be in order, even if not in graphics.

Comment: ![Network diagram we are planning to route nat via proxy ][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UOscZ.png

Comment: What route does data take from the default gateway to the internet? What route does data take from the squid proxy to client?

Answer (score 4):

To transparently intercept traffic use [policy based routing](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.html) via NAT to redirect the web traffic to the squid proxy, then intercept it.

- Set policy routing on your GW or NAT box, adjust the ip's and interfaces to suit. Your diagram implies the first rule to allow your squid box access to the internet might not be needed.

  ```
  iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 80 -s squidip
  iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j MARK --set-mark 8 -p tcp --dport 80
  ip rule add fwmark 8 table 2
  ip route add default via squidip dev eth0 table 2
  ```
- Then intercept on the Squid Proxy. This rule can be more specific if there's any chance other data on port 80 needs to go through this box.

  ```
  iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3129
  ```
- On the Squid box, `squid.conf`

  ```
  http_port 3129 intercept
  ```

If you need to support IPV6, [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) have a [tproxy config example](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept/CentOsTproxy4) for CentOS.